# Block Diagram using tikz and positioning the descriptive text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a diagram like below:

[image]

So far I have got this:

[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
    auto,
    decision/.style = { diamond, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,
                        text width=5em, text badly centered,
                        inner sep=1pt, rounded corners },
    block/.style    = { rectangle, draw=blue, thick, 
                        fill=blue!20, text width=10em, text centered,
                        rounded corners, minimum height=2em },
    line/.style     = { draw, thick, ->, shorten >=1pt },
  ]

  % Define nodes in a matrix
  \matrix [column sep=5mm, row sep=10mm] {
                    & \node [block] (data) {\textsf{A}};   & \\

                    & \node [block] (IFFT) {\textsf{B}}; & \\
                    & \node [block] (pesos)
                        {\textsf{C}};            & \\
                    & \node [block] (filtrado)
                        {\textsf{G}};          & \\
                    %& \node [text centered] (xf) {$\hat{x}(t)$ };          & \\
  };
  % connect all nodes defined above
  \begin{scope} [every path/.style=line]
    \path (data)      --    node [near start] {Something} (IFFT);
    \path (IFFT)    --    node [near start] {} (pesos);
    \path (pesos)    --    node [near start] {Something} (filtrado);

  \end{scope}
  %

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone please let me know how can I add the two blocks which are on the sides? Also the position of the text which are below the box need to be moved beside the box. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing *Something* as part of the line, it can be set as a label to the node. Using `label={angle:Text}` you can set it anywhere around the node you like. Since I am not very familiar with the matrix positioning I rather use `positioning` (included with `\usetikzlibrary`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
  node distance=10mm and 15mm,
    auto,
    decision/.style = { diamond, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,
                        text width=5em, text badly centered,
                        inner sep=1pt, rounded corners },
    block/.style    = { rectangle, draw=blue, thick, 
                        fill=blue!20, text width=10em, text centered,
                        rounded corners, minimum height=2em },
    line/.style     = { draw, thick, ->, shorten >=1pt },
  ]

  \node [block,label={0:Something 1}] (data) {\textsf{A}};
  \node [block,below=of data] (IFFT) {\textsf{B}};
  \node [block, below=of IFFT,label={0:Something 2}] (pesos) {\textsf{C}};
  \node [block,below=of pesos] (filtrado) {\textsf{G}};
  \path (pesos)--(filtrado) node [pos=.5,left=25mm,block] (lefty) {\textsf{E}};
  \path (pesos)--(filtrado) node [pos=.5,right=25mm,block] (righty) {\textsf{F}};
  % connect all nodes defined above
  \begin{scope} [every path/.style=line]
    \path (data)      --  (IFFT);
    \path (IFFT)    --   (pesos);
    \path (pesos)    --  (filtrado);
    \path (lefty) -- (pesos |- lefty);
    \path (righty) -- (pesos |- righty);    
  \end{scope}
  %

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]